# Language Definition Question

Tags: programming-languages, language-design

Can someone please help me understand exactly what this means?

```
<stmt> := var <ident> = <expr>
    | <ident> = <expr>
    | for <ident> = <expr> to <expr> do <stmt> end
    | read_int <ident>
    | print <expr>
    | <stmt> ; <stmt>

<expr> := <string>
    | <int>
    | <arith_expr>
    | <ident>

<bin_expr> := <expr> <bin_op> <expr>
<bin_op> := + | - | * | /

<ident> := <char> <ident_rest>*
<ident_rest> := <char> | <digit>

<int> := <digit>+
<digit> := 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9

<string> := " <string_elem>* "
<string_elem> := <any char other than ">
```

In the first part, I'm assuming `<ident>` means "Identifier", and `<expr>` means "Expression" and `<arith_expr>` means "Arithmatic Expression". But the rest is a little confusing to me.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<stmt> := var <ident> = <expr>
    | <ident> = <expr>
    | for <ident> = <expr> to <expr> do <stmt> end
    | read_int <ident>
    | print <expr>
    | <stmt> ; <stmt>
```

Translation: A statement can be either

- a variable declaration (with an expression)
- a variable assignment (with an expression)
- a for() loop (with two expressions and a statement)
- read_int (with an identifier)
- print (with an expression)
- two statements separated by a semicolon

---

```
<expr> := <string>
    | <int>
    | <arith_expr>
    | <ident>
```

Translation: An expression can be either

- a string literal
- and integer
- an arithmetic expression
- an identifier

---

```
<bin_expr> := <expr> <bin_op> <expr>
<bin_op> := + | - | * | /
```

A binary expression consists of two expressions and a binary operator inbetween. Binary operators are:

```
+ - * /
```

---

```
<ident> := <char> <ident_rest>*
<ident_rest> := <char> | <digit>
```

An identifier always starts with a character, but the rest of the identifier can consist of characters and digits

---

```
<int> := <digit>+
<digit> := 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

definition of a digit

---

```
<string> := " <string_elem>* "
<string_elem> := <any char other than ">
```

definition of a string literal

Answer (score 4):

Maybe should brush up on your [Backus Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)-reading skills.

Answer (score 2):

```
<stmt>        = Statement
<expr>        = Expression
<bin_expr>    = Binary expression (Expression involving <bin_op>)
<bin_op>      = Binary operator
<ident>       = Identifier
<ident_rest>  = Rest of identifier
<int>         = Integer
<digit>       = Digit
<string>      = String
<string_elem> = String element
```